# Undefined Index

Tags: php, cakephp

Estou a ter um erro ao passar os dados da base de dados para a view, só que o código é praticamente igual a outro que tenho, e que funciona correctamente. O Array com os dados também está a ser enviado para a view, mas o `User` em `$users['User']['...'];` provoca este erro. Como se resolve este problema?

**Controller**

```
    public function admin_mod_password(){

        $this->loadModel('User');
        $users = $this->User->find('all');
        $this->set('users', $users);
        $this->layout='admin_index';

    }
```

**View**

```
<h2>Modificar a Password</h2>
<br>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <p>Nome de Administrador: </p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $users['User']['username']; ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <p>Password actual: </p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $users['User']['password'];?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**Model**

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
//http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/pt/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html
class User extends AppModel {   
    public $useTable = 'users';
    public $name = 'User';
    public $validate = array(
        'username' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'A username is required'
            )
        ),
        'password' => array(
            'required' => array(
                    'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'A password is required'
            )
        ),
        'role' => array(
            'valid' => array(
                'rule' => array('inList', array('admin', 'author')),
                'message' => 'Please enter a valid role',
                'allowEmpty' => false
            )
        )
    );
}
?>
```

**var_dump($users)**

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'User' => 
        array (size=7)
          'id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'username' => string 'teste' (length=5)
          'password' => string 'teste' (length=5)
          'created' => string '0000-00-00 00:00:00' (length=19)
          'modified' => string '0000-00-00 00:00:00' (length=19)
          'role' => string 'admin' (length=5)
          'user_id' => string '1' (length=1)
```

Comment: Poste o resultado do `var_dump()` da variável `$users`

Comment: @gmsantos Já coloquei.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bastou apenas alterar o controller para:

```
    public function admin_mod_password(){

    $this->loadModel('User');
    $users = $this->User->find('first');
    $this->set('users', $users);
    $this->layout='admin_index';

}
```

Obrigado ao gmsantos por me ajudar a chegar lá.

Answer (score 2):

O erro está em sua view.

Você está retornando uma lista de usuários em `$this->User->find('all');` porém na sua view você está exibindo os dados de um único usuário.

Para exibir a lista na view, utilize algum tipo de [estrutura de repetição](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.control-structures.php) do PHP, como o [`foreach`](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php) por exemplo

**View**

```
<h2>Modificar a Password</h2>
<br>
<table>
<?php foreach($users as $user): ?>
<tr>
    <td>
        <p>Nome de Administrador: </p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $user['User']['username']; ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <p>Password actual: </p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $user['User']['password'];?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Eu já tinha experimentado isso, no entanto vou experimentar outro `find()`.